# Test API Key to return mock data with Django Rest Framework and TokenAuthentication

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm building a REST-ful API using Django Rest Framework. I have handled integration with REST APIs before for work and have been given test API keys specifically for use with testing for integration, keys that allow you to send data and returns mock data, but doesn't put the data in the system. I am trying to implement this same feature in my API, but I haven't been able to find a way to do so yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use some decorator to do that :)

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
def mock_funcname(func):

    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = authenticate(token=request.REQUEST['token'])
        if user.id == 'TEST USER ID':
            return Response({'detail': "Some stuff mocked for this user :)"})
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

So now you can put it like other decorator :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@mock_funcname
def funcname(request, pid=None):
    return response......
```

Its a basic function you need to make it more complicate

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can install [mommy](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy) to create mock data in your tests.
So in your tests.py you can create a test to your API, checking the status_code and the response:

```
def test(self):
   user = mommy.make(User) # Create a fake user
   token = Token.objects.get(user__username=user.username) # Generate a token
   self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key) # Token for your request
   response = self.client.post("url", your_data) # POST in your URL
   self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED) # Status Code of Creation
   self.assertEqual(User.objects.last().first_name, user.first_name) # Check the fields created
```

and then run the tests running `python manage.py test` or follow the documetation in [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/)

Comment: Will mommy work for live integration testing instead of unit test runs?

Comment: I do not think so! Because it create a fake database running `manage.py test`. But if you do not want to save in your system the request given a key, is better to use [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/) so you can separate you test database from your real database.